# R: writing the data related to each unique occurence into a separate file using for loop

Tags: r, sorting, csv, for-loop, external-sorting

I am a beginner to coding in R.
I have 60 unique ID's in a column with each unique ID having 30 entries, I would like to write a code which automatically creates separate files for each unique ID.
This code worked for a single ID

```
unique(src$ID)
ID2<- subset(src, ID=='099857')
write.csv(pat2,file= "D:/R/ID2.csv")
```

when I try to loop it using the following code.

```
for (i in 1:length(unique(src$ID)))
{ unique(src$ID)
  id<- subset(src, ID== "i")
  paste(id)
  write.csv(i,file="D:R/i.csv")
}
```

I get a file that just counts all the unique IDs (60) and pastes them into an excel sheet.

trying to incorporate the structure for a single ID into an automated loop.

## expected output- 60 unique files with 30 entries each.

Does anybody have any suggestions?
Thank you.

Comment: It looks as though you are trying to save to a specific directory in your ```write.csv(i, file ="D:R/i.csv")```. If so, best to set the 'working directory' you want to save to using ```setwd("D:R/")```. You can do this prior to the ```for``` loop. That way your filename argument in ```write.csv``` would become ```paste0(i, ".csv")``` as @Chris suggests.

Comment: Or an other solution without loop ``sapply(unique(src$ID), FUN = function(x, df = src) write.csv(subset(df, ID == x), file = paste0("D:/R/", x,".csv")))``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are iterating over a numeric vector (1:length(unique(src$ID)), but in the loop you refer to i as a character vector "i". Try changing it to:

```
for(i in unique(src$ID)) {
ID2 <- subset(src, ID == i)
write.csv(ID2, file = paste0("D:/R/",i,".csv"))
}
```

...if the name of the column that contains the ID is "SampleID," then you should change it to:

```
 for(i in unique(src$SampleID)) {
    ID2 <- subset(src, SampleID == i)
    write.csv(ID2, file = paste0("D:/R/",i,".csv"))
    }
```

Comment: Chris, Thank you. The code is currently giving an output file with all the dimnames but no data. Do you think using a nested for loop will help? Yes, I would like to be able to loop through characters as the ID is alpha numeric.

Comment: Can you give me the results of this command: head(src)   ....I see in your first post that you are trying to write the data from pat2 into the csv file. Are you sure you want the data from pat2 and not the data from ID2 (which I assume is a subset of the src dataframe).

Comment: #pat2
unique(src$SampleID)
pat2<- subset(src, SampleID=='R4683_58min')
write.csv(pat2,file= "D:/R/pat2.csv")

This is a code that works for a single unique sampleID from the large data set,
I am trying to use a loop it so that it automatically queries for the "SampleID==" and saves the data subset under the same name in a separate csv file.

hope this helps. Again,thank you so much for your time.

Comment: you have to exchange "ID" for SampleID...see my edited answer